# Decision level fusion

Tags: classification, deep-learning, decision

I have trained three deep learning models, and used majority voting for the final decision. Applying majority voting has led to improving the accuracy of the classifier with all test samples, except with only two samples, where the three models differ in their decision, and thus no majority was obtained. How can I deal with this situation? How tie breaking can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there's no indication of a winner, you can just pick one at random - that can't be worse on average than just doing one model, if all three models are equally likely to be correct.

You might have an indication of a winner, though: Run a bit of statistics on these three models to find that which is in the "winning" decision set most often. That's your most reliable model. (By the way, that model should be your benchmark model.)